# Как лучше организовать передачу данных через веб-сервер?

Tags: c#, node.js, сервер, http, client

Есть связка: `win-приложение 1 <-> веб сервер на nodejs <-> win приложение 2`.

Необходимо реализовать передачу данных через эту связку.

Из первого приложения получаю/передаю данные на сервер при помощи сокетов.

Проблема в том, что второе приложение может лишь отправлять HTTP запросы, т.е. получить новые данные можно только путём получения инфы возвращаемой из POST.

Так вот, есть два выхода из ситуации:

1. Выводить из второго приложения данные в файл, затем считывать его на сервере и уже отправлять в первое приложение через сокеты;
2. Передавать через POST, как я и говорил ранее.

Стоить ещё учесть, что передача информации идёт каждые 300мс.
Как поступить? Не вижу какого-то иного решения:(

Comment: Что-то я вашей проблемы не пойму, ну сделайте у сервера два интерфейса, где один будет обрабатывать сокеты и отдавать данные в реал тайме, а другой, простой REST API, где клиент сам будет раз в N сек получать данные и отсылать новые средствами простых POST/GET.

Comment: А почему бы не использовать открытый WebSocket? И в него отправлять нужные данные, не придется долбать сервер частыми запросами.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо за ответ. Я проблему вижу в том, что через POST/GET слишком часто будут данные на сервер уходить, не помрёт ли он от такого?

aepot, да с удовольствием бы сокеты использовал, но api второго приложения такого не предусматривает.

Comment: Ну а у вас тогда есть выбор? К чему тогда весь этот вопрос, если у вас попросту нету выбора и только REST API и остается? А вот помрет или нет - это уже дело другое, тут скорей всего надо отправлять и получать данные "пачкой", например чат, где вы раз в секунду получаете не одно сообщение, а все, что были за это время отправлены, ну то есть некая синхронизация данных в небольшой промежуток времени, а сам сервер выдержит или нет, уже вопрос, 300мс для большинства серверов это критично, обычно делают сикундную задержку, может чуть меньше...

Comment: Немного уточню то, что я предложил в первом варианте. Т.е. на стороне второго приложения поднять сокет клиент, на том же node.js, в нём уже считывать вывод приложения в файл и отправлять на сервер.

Comment: Если серверу нечего ответить на поллинг запрос, можно отправлять кешированный ответ, что данных нет. Можно даже минипрокси сделать, которая будет работать с сервером нормально, а с приложением через поллинг. А вообще для поллинга есть http заголовок `RetryAfter`, который отправляется сервером клинту, чтобы тот повторил запрос через указанное время. Проверьте, вдруг он поддерживается клиентом, тогда сможете со стороны сервера управлять частотой запросов.